# Deployment в Jenkins конкретного билда на конкретный сервер

Tags: jenkins, release-management

Использую Pipeline Multibranch Plugin

Есть сервера: dev, test, staging, production

При пуше в ветку dev - Jenkins автоматически деплоит её на dev сервер

Как сделать так, что бы я мог вручную задеплоить любую ветку на test и на staging?
А при необходимости - откатить обратно.
Артифакты хранить не обязательно, достаточно просто брать revision с git и по ней вытягивать нужную ветку
Меня даже устроит если Jenkins просто вызовет мой bash скрипт передав в него среду и ревизию, а дальше я всё сделаю сам в скрипте

Дело в том что перед тем как мерджить бранч в dev, тестировщик должен задеплоить его на тестовый сервер и протестить, что бы в случае если там баги и до релиза их не успеют пофиксить - то мы не будем мерджить этот бранч, а просто релизнемся без него
Ну а на стайджинг и на прод естественно хотим деплоить "мышкой" из дженкинса, выбирая конкретный билд

Подобное в Attlasian Bamboo очень хорошо реализовано (хоть он и хранит артифакты), и после него этой функциональности очень не хватает в Jenkins
Там это выглядит так: [image: Deploy in Bamboo]